# How to Merge Pre-approval keys for the same user in Paypal Adaptive Payment

Tags: php, paypal, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have implemented paypal's Pre-approval adaptive payment for my crowdfunding website.

So when a user makes the pledge for any project, A Unique pre-approval key is generated, And The same user can pledge multiple time for the same project which generates different pre-approval key for each pledge made.

Now, If i Finalize the payment keeping each transaction unique then paypal will charge for every transaction and this would become costly.

So, Is there any way that i can Merge the transactions made by same user and treat it as single payment to reduce the paypal commission.

**NOTE: Paypal Confirmed my client that this is possible. But i doubt.**

Answer (score 0):

Of course, that would be no problem at all.

First, you don't need to create multiple pre-approval keys for the same user.  A single preapproval key would be enough, you just need to make sure the profile is setup so that it can cover the total of all pledges made by the user.

Your app would calculate that total and generate a single Pay API request with the amount set to that total.

That said, I don't see how you're going to be saving any money on fees.  2.9% is 2.9% no matter how you slice it.

Comment: Paypal Fees is Actually (2.9% + $0.30) for each transaction, And here this matters.

Btw, What if i use the first pre-approval key and amount as the sum. will it work?

Comment: Ah, yes, the 30¢ would be dinged each time.  As long as the first preapproval profile was setup to allow you to charge as much as you need then yes, it would work.

Comment: Sorry @Andrew Angell , But the problem still exist, The profile will never be set to as much as i need :( ... Any Other solution?

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is.  How could the profile never be set to as much as you need.  You're the one creating the profile.  Just set to what you need.

Comment: What do you mean by a profile?

My understanding for a profile is "Paypal Account". and if i am right, then there are 3 profiles included. 1st is "Sender", 2nd is "Primary Receiver" and 3rd is "Me (Secondary Receiver)". So I can set the profile of only me, not anybody else's. Please advise if i am getting you wrong.

Comment: I'm talking about the "preapproval profile" that you're creating.